# Separate logs for ServiceMix features or bundles

Tags: log4j, apache-servicemix, sifting-appender

I have a ServiceMix 7 instance configured to log for each bundle in its own log file. There are two problems I have noticed with this setup:

1. Log events appear in both the bundle's log file as well as the default servicemix.log. How can I log in just one of the files? Ideally, I'm looking for a way to ensure that bundle events are not also logged in servicemix.log.
2. I see logs for every active bundle that needs to log something. Is there a way to specify just a few bundles that should have their own log files, and have the rest log to the default servicemix.log?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I'm curious how you created this configuration.  I would like to have some separate log files.